# Sharing app content to stage - Insufficient RSC permission

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

sharing the content of our app hasn't worked for a week.

Using the Teams WebApp we are getting the following errors in the developer console:

```
CID[main] ShareExtensibleAppButtonContainer: Installed app is undefined or doesn't have authorization
Insufficient RSC permission for appId:'XXXXXXX' with isChannelMeeting: false
```

it worked last month, and nothing was changed from our side.

I tried to set the following permissions, but it has had no effect.

```
"authorization": {
    "permissions": {
      "orgWide": [],
      "resourceSpecific": [
        {
          "name": "MeetingStage.Write.Chat",
          "type": "Delegated"
        },
        {
          "name": "ChannelMeetingStage.Write.Group",
          "type": "Delegated"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

could anyone help me to get it working?

Thank you

Comment: Have you added the appContentUrl in validDomains array inside manifest.json? Are you getting 1000 response code?

Comment: sure the url was always there and it worked. The content can also be loaded in SidePanel. but after the click on share button nothing happens. no 1000 response code,  only the errors listed above

Comment: I have tried it again and it works now! nothing have changed from my side

Comment: There was similar issue happening for few users for which ICM was already raised. Engineering team has fixed it temporarily. So that's the reason issue is not happening. Thanks for confirming that it's working now.

Comment: the next problem: We are able to share the content, but the new attandees are getting the error "Can't show this content, Your admin has disabled the app that's being shared" 

There are no restictions for this app. It looks like that the app couldn't be loaded quickly enough. If the user closes the Teams meeting and opens it again, the app is already loaded and the content is visible.

Comment: @MRoutchkan - Are you still facing this issue (new attendees are getting the error), or it has already resolved?